# Arcmap - automatic print area per one feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data-driven-pages

I have hundreds of routes in vector shpfile. They have different lenghts and I want to create one map per one feature - route- in shapefile. Unfortunatelly size of print area will be different for each route (I want to keep only the same scale for each). I don't want to prepare for everyone manually size before printing. Is there tool/solution which allow to automatically prepare print size for each feature (one feature-one route) with fixed scale?

Comment: Can you use the "Center and Maintain Current Scale" or "Data Driven Scale" options in the DDP extent setup? Maybe something like what's discussed in [this thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/109005)?

Comment: will you only be printing one map per feature, or might you be printing multiple maps for the larger ones?

Answer (score 2):

Make use of Data Driven Pages. In ArcMap, in Layout View, set the scale you wish to be maintained for your maps. In your data driven pages setup box, under extent, click the **Center And Maintain Current Scale**. Now your scale will not change regardless of feature size.

[image: Center And Maintain Current Scale]

If you want a maximum scale set you may want to check out my blog on the subject [here](http://emilsarcpython.blogspot.com/2015/11/creating-data-driven-pages-with-maximum.html).